# Uitable union by row

Tags: matlab

I have program to display data in a uitable:

```
data_plat = load('Data_Plat.mat');   
Database_All = data_plat.Database_All;   
data2 = table2cell(Database_All(strcmpi(Database_All.Plat, final_output), ...
                                        {'Plat', 'Nama', 'Jurusan', 'Status'}));   
handles.uitable1.Data = union(handles.uitable1.Data, data2);
```

this code show by column(downward) in table, how to show that by row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the transpose operator (`.'`) to swap rows with columns.

For example, change your last line to this:

```
handles.uitable1.Data = union(handles.uitable1.Data, data2).';
```

**Proof of concept**

```
figure;
t=uitable;
t.Data = {'Foo','foo'};
s={'Bar','bar'};
t.Data = union(t.Data,s);  % gives one row
t.Data = union(t.Data,s).'; % gives one column
```

Comment: i think something wrong about my code or i should not use union for solve my problem(replicate data in table), ty guys